# Can I upgrade to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with thinkpad T420 graphic hardware?

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, upgrade, graphics

I am currently using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, and I'm trying to upgrade to 14.04 LTS, it tells me "Your graphics hardware may not be fully supported in Ubuntu 14.04". My output using `lspci | grep VGA` gives the following:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF119M [Quadro NVS 4200M] (rev a1)
```

Is it because that my NVIDIA hardware is really not suitable for 14.04, or is it due to some improper configurations that has made the system ignored my NVIDIA graphic card and could only see my integrated graphics card instead? What should I do in this case? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Just to clarify 15.04 is no LTS version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is perfectly solved. Here's the link (another question I asked about driver settings):
[nvidia-settings won't work properly in Ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/681014/nvidia-settings-wont-work-properly-in-ubuntu-12-04/681040#681040)

Basically the drivers weren't properly installed, and after removing all packages from nvidia the update manager worked fine. The packages can be later correcty installed after the update is complete.

Answer (score 0):

Your video card is supported starting with [`nvidia-270`](http://www.nvidia.com/object/linux-display-ia32-270.41.06-driver) (for 32-bit systems).

### For 14.04

Install at least `nvidia-346` via

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-346
```

To install [`nvidia-352`](http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/90279/en-us) you need an additional PPA

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352  
sudo reboot
```

### For 12.04

Install at least `nvidia-340` via

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-340
```

To install version `nvidia-346` you need an additional PPA

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-346
sudo reboot
```

Comment: I tried to install nvidia-346 and it says: `E: Package 'nvidia-346' has no installation candidate`, and the same for version 352. What does it mean? By the way, may I ask how to know which nvidia driver version to install?

Comment: You asked for 14.04, not 12.04

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Thanks. now I can update the driver, but the problem still exists. After upgrading the driver the update manager still complains about the graphic hardware.

Comment: With which message?

Comment: As I wrote in the question: "Your graphics hardware may not be fully supported in Ubuntu 14.04". Recommended me not to update because it might be very slow. This is not a command window output, I'm using update manager GUI at this point. It is a pop window warning me not to update.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29768/discussion-between-cathias-and-a-b).