# nvidia-settings won't work properly in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, drivers, nvidia

I am using Ubuntu 12.04.5. I want to upgrade to 14.04 but the update manager told me that my graphics hardware might not be suitable for 14.04, like this:

```
Your graphics hardware may not be fully supported in Ubuntu 14.04.

Running the 'unity' desktop environment is not fully supported by your graphics hardware. 
You will maybe end up in a very slow environment after the upgrade. 
Our advice is to keep the LTS version for now. For more information see 
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Bugs/UpdateManagerWarningForUnity3D 
Do you still want to continue with the upgrade?
```

My output of `lspci | grep VGA` gives the following:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF119M [Quadro NVS 4200M] (rev a1)
```

I don't know if it was the driver's problem, so I started to configure my nvidia driver. When I execute:

```
$ nvidia-settings
```

I get the following messages:

```
** (nvidia-settings:3220): WARNING **: PRIME: Failed to execute child process "/usr/bin/prime-supported" (No such file or directory)
** Message: PRIME: is it supported? no

ERROR: nvidia-settings could not find the registry key file. This file should
   have been installed along with this driver at
   /usr/share/nvidia/nvidia-application-profiles-key-documentation. The
   application profiles will continue to work, but values cannot be
   preopulated or validated, and will not be listed in the help text.
   Please see the README for possible values and descriptions.
```

So I tried this:

```
$ sudo apt-get install nvidia-prime
```

Then my GUI won't work anymore after a reboot. I was left with command line when I started the system. I removed the package and I am back to GUI. Does anyone know what the problem is here?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your nVidia driver is not correctly installed and that is the reason why the upgrade complains:
It's falling back to the Integrated Graphics... Depending on your processor speed, that one might be slow.

My advice is:

1. Take a full system back-up using [CloneZilla](http://clonezilla.org)
2. Remove the nvidia driver:

   ```
    sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
   ```
3. Upgrade
4. Install the nvidia driver again using the Q&A [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/680825/how-do-i-have-to-install-nvidia-gpu-drivers-properly/680826#680826) under 14.04.